# How to Randomize Images for "Animated Responsive Image Grid"

Tags: javascript

"Animated Responsive Image Grid" (from tympanus.net/codrops) displays images only in a sequential order, and in the image grid, it changes from either one image up to any number of images that are configured to change at at a time.
I have it set to change 3 random images at a time.

I've tried using "var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length);" etc, but I can't get it to work. How can it be made to load images in a random order?

```
<div id="ri-grid" class="ri-grid ri-grid-size-3">                                                                           
   <ul>                    
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/1.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/2.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/3.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/4.jpg"/></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: May I see the script you use to load the image?

Comment: Make a try of following snippet - `var index = Math.floor((Math.random()*10) % (imgs.length+1)); index = index == 0? 1 : index;`

Comment: Thanks, but that snippet doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who can use this randomization of images in a UL list, here is the working cross-browser solution:

The Script:

```
  var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
          for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {
          ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);
    }
```

The HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/1.jpg"/>1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/2.jpg"/>2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/3.jpg"/>3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/4.jpg"/>4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

By this you can randomize your image orders, javascript need to be involved in this task.

First I get the main element of the HTML, get all the children in array to random it, at the end give you the result:

```js
var numbers = document.querySelector('#numbers');
var list = Array.from(numbers.children);
var newlist;

list.sort(function(a, b) {
  return -1 + Math.random() * 3; // -1, 0, or 1
});

while (numbers.children.length > 0) {
  numbers.removeChild(numbers.children[0]);
}
list.forEach(function(el) {
  numbers.appendChild(el);
});
```

```html
<ul id="numbers">
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/1.jpg"/>1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/2.jpg"/>2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/3.jpg"/>3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/4.jpg"/>4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** something it gives you the same result, but most of the time randomize it, as we know we're not using AI to not give us the old result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help. Your addition works to randomize image loading in firefox only. What would make it work in other browsers as well, like IE?

Answer (score 0):

We really need to see the JavaScript you're using to invoke the plugin to tell what's going on. However, I noticed that your div doesn't have an id. If you're just using the default JavaScript that they provide in their sample, change your HTML to the following to get it to work:

```
<div id="ri-grid" class="ri-grid ri-grid-size-1 ri-shadow">                                                                           
   <ul>                    
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/1.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/2.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/3.jpg"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="images/medium/4.jpg"/></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Make sure to leave the id in. The ri-grid id is how they refer to the div when they make the following call in their sample code:

```
$( '#ri-grid' ).gridrotator();
```